# Dismiss two NavigationController in same time

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

[image: My storyboard]

I want to come back from the last page to the first one with popToRootController when I click on the grey button at the bottom of the page.

I don't understand how I can act on both Navigation controller in the sameTime. I use a lib for the two last page. [SideMenu Lib](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)

All I could do actually is to dismiss the last Navigation controller and land on the blue page, and it's not what I need.

Comment: Basically it should be enough to pop the outer one because the inner one won't really be visible anymore. If the second one is presented, just dismiss it without animation and pop the outer one in the callback.

Comment: @Sulthan Do you have some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:true)
```

**OR**

if it's the root

```
let vc = //

let nav = // set vc as root

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootviewController = nav
```

//

**OR**

```
if let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootviewController as? UINavigationController {

    root.popToRootViewController(animated:true)

 }
```

Comment: The last one was the good, juste have to inset this code inside a dismiss for close the sideMenu